# Deserialise XML and add to SQL Server using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an XML file that from a third party and I want to populate tables in my SQL Server database from the data contained in it.

I've created classes for the data, applied the necessary keys etc but cannot get the data to load. I'm going around in circles with various issues.

Here is my sample XML:

```
<root>
    <owners>
        <owner>
          <forename>Simon</forename>
          <surname>Smith</surname>
          <ownerid>1</ownerid>
          <cars>
            <car>
              <make>Volkswagen</make>
              <model>Beetle</model>
              <reg>YRL908T</reg>
            </car>
            <car>
              <make>Range Rover</make>
              <model>Velar</model>
              <reg>AB23ABC</reg>
            </car>
          </cars>
        </owner>
        <owner>
          <forename>Brian</forename>
          <surname>Bloggs</surname>
          <ownerid>15</ownerid>
          <cars>
            <car>
              <make>Volkswagen</make>
              <model>Polo</model>
              <reg>ABC123Y</reg>
            </car>
          </cars>
        </owner>
    </owners>
</root>
```

Here are my derived classes to enable me to deseralise this XML:

```
[Table("_SBCar")]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "car")]
public class Car 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "make")]
    public string Make { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "model")]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "reg")]
    public string Reg { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CarId { get; set; }
}

[Table("_SBOwnerCars")]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "cars")]
public class Cars
{
    [ForeignKey("FK__SBOwnerCars__SBOwners")]
    public virtual int OwnerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FK__SBOwnerCars__SBCar")]
    public virtual int CarId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "car")]
    public List<Car> Car { get; set; }
}

[Table("_SBOwners")]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "owner")]
public class Owner
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "forename")]
    public string Forename { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ownerid")]
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "cars")]
    public Cars Cars { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "owners")]
public class Owners
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "owner")]
    public List<Owner> Owner { get; set; }       
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "owners")]
    public Owners Owners { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following set up in the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
public class CarContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().Property(p => p.CarId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().UseIdentityColumn();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>().HasOne<Cars>(h => h.Cars);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cars>().HasKey(h => new { h.OwnerId, h.CarId });
    }

    public DbSet<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in my code, I simply deserialise my data and try to add one of the owners:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(doc.OuterXml))
{
    test = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}

using (var db = new CarContext(ConnectionString))
{
    db.Owners.Add(test.Owners.Owner[1]);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I am getting this error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__SBOwnerCars__SBCar". The conflict occurred in database "NSCPNottsTest", table "dbo._SBCar", column 'CarId'.
> The statement has been terminated.

I think it's because the `CarId` is not being auto-generated for some reason. I started out with a full head of hair but have now pulled most of it out. Is anyone able to see what I'm doing wrong so I can keep the tuft I have left?

Thanks

Comment: curious question, is a single `Car` can be owned by multiple `Owner`? looking at your `Cars` class it does implies that way. the POCO do makes sense for the xml but it doesn't seem to be representative of what you want to do in the SQL. i suggest separate them into two different kind of POCO, one for xml and the other for ef.

Comment: How can a Car ID be applied to a List of Cars?  An ID is unique.  You can have a list of cars of the same model.  The error is occurring because you have duplicate keys.

Comment: Hi - the model is purely a proof of concept for a much larger and more complex data structure.  A Car has a unique registration number and therefore you can have many makes and models the same but it will be a unique car because of the registration number.

Comment: Basically, I have an owner who can have many cars.  I then want an intermediate table to link owners to cars.  That's it really.

Comment: A single car can only have a single owner but an owner can have multiple cars.

Comment: The key is auto-generated, so how can it be unique?  It appears to be unique because, when attempting to save, they are all 0?